# How would I exactly duplicate a USB drive?

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive, usb-storage, usb-3, duplicate

I have a standard USB flash drive that I have partitioned and formatted and organized and done quite a lot of things to. I was hoping to create another copy of that drive, with partitions and everything intact, and doing it manually would be an absolute chore (and not an acceptable option if I were to produce many more). Is there any way (in bash or something) that I could make another USB thumb drive of the same model exactly the same?

I am on a MacBook Pro that I dual boot with Ubuntu.

Comment: This is trivial with linux, what OS are you using?

Comment: True. ANd not to nitpick but probably trivial for any unix like. (e.g. including BSD's, OS X, AIX, ... ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned "bash" I assume you are using Linux or some Unix variant (You may want to specify this in the summary) If this is the case, simply use "DD"

Plug both disks in the drive, MAKING SURE YOU KNOW WHICH DRIVE IS ASSOCIATED WITH WHICH DEVICE.  (IF YOU GET THIS WRONG YOU COULD OVERWRITE THE SOURCE DRIVE OR WORSE !!!)

If the disk you want to copy is /dev/sdb  and the new blank is /dev/sdc
1.  Ensure both are unmounted.  (You can use df to check this).  If they are not, unmount
    them.
2.  Issue the command "dd if=/dev/sdb of=/dev/sdc"  and wait.  It will do a bit copy 
    between the disks.

Comment: Might want to specify a larger than default block size to improve performance. Try `bs=1M` or something like that.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for that answer! I thought of something else, however, and thought I'd dig up this question. Would there be any way of storing the copy of the drive in a file, so you could restore it later and use it for multiple other drives without the original?

Comment: of-course, you can use file instead of /dev/sdX, and in that way you can read to a file and later write to a disk.

Answer (score 2):

[win32 image writer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/) is what I'd use on windows - it does a pretty good, simple job at making images, and applying it to a raw drive. On linux, I guess you could use dd.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>First thing that popped up my mind was [Acronis Disk Director](http://www.acronis.com/homecomputing/products/diskdirector/#features).</strike>

Maybe gparted can do the same. Looking into that.

[Gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/) can do what you want, independently of OS, if you use the Live CD.

Answer (score 0):

Use [imageUSB](http://osforensics.com/tools/write-usb-images.html) to create exact bit-level copies

1. Select your old USB drive and choose `Create from UFD`.
   It will save a BIN file somewhere on your computer
2. Select your new USB drive and `Write to UFD`
   It will copy th BIN file back and you're done

[image]

Comment: I haven't tried this, but I'm suspicious of it referring to drives by drive letter and including information about file system type. That would seem to point to it working on partitions, not whole devices, while the OP wants the latter.

Comment: I don't see the point. What should be wrong with this method? Where does he state that he doesn't have any drive letter?

Comment: I'm not saying there's anything *wrong* with this method or answer, I am just saying that I wouldn't be so sure the tool you mention (based on the screenshot shown) works on whole devices rather than only partitions. The OP explicitly mentions wanting "partitions and everything intact" on the copy.

Comment: Ah, I get it. I would expect the tool to let me select multiple partitions as there are little checkmarks as seen on screenshot